# Block copy in assembler

Tags: memory, assembly, copy

My project - RAM speed testing utilite. 
So I used MOVSD (as MOV with the biggest size block DW) to read some memory from one source and write to another. But the results that I got display that RAM isn't used, but instead is used memory cache, because read/write speed is 768 MByte/s in DDR2 SDRAM.

So I need the instruction or function in assembler for 80x86 to move big block to memory, to overflow cache and testing memory, not cache testing. I use Assembler because I don't need optimizations that C/C++ do, I rewriting different blocks of memory and compiler may think that it isn't need, and destroy my test. That's why I don't use memcpy and others.

Comment: Isn't disabling compiler optimization enough for your project?

Comment: Cpu cache/memory does not equal ram!!!  To use ram, you need to allocate memory

Comment: @Gunner: Nonsense. The cache is usually quite transparent to the developer: It does get used automagically. You can't avoid the use of the cache by `malloc`, you need special instructions to bypass the cache.

Comment: Disabling optimization may be enough, or may not. it's depend on compiler. But I want to be sure.

Comment: Gunner, I allocate memory using WinAPI VirtualAlloc(). drhirsch, can you suggest where I can find this instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move a bigger block than the size of the largest cache and make sure you use `movntdq` for writing and `movntdqa` for reading.

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what I need. But there is problem with my using of Inline Assembler in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Here the code, that doesn't work:                                                                       void* c = (void*)malloc(16);
 double* pointer2 = new double[4];
 pointer2[0] = 0;
 pointer2[1] = 2;
 pointer2[3] = 0;
 pointer2[4] = 4;
 //__asm movntdq xmm0, 0
 __asm movups xmm0, pointer2
 __asm movntdq c, xmm0

Comment: A 16 byte block is far to small. And don't do something like new double[4] (to much java?). Allocate small arrays on the stack, and only big stuff (lets say 4k or more) on the heap. The problem with your code is most likely the alignment. A 16 byte alignment is required. Also keep in mind that the processor always loads a complete cache line, never a single byte (or 16).

Comment: I uploaded some ancient code I have written a few years ago, a memory benchmark which basically does exactly what you want. The code is mostly non portable (It runs on _my_ system :-)), but of course you may get something out of the assembler loops: https://github.com/gpiez/membench